# Download large file to server using php with any method

Tags: php, curl, ftp, download

**First try:**

I have used this code: (thanks to [user580950](https://stackoverflow.com/users/580950/user580950) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9248100/315550))

```
// define some variables
$local_file = 'archive.tar';
$server_file = '/path/to/archive.tar';
$ftp_server = "1.2.3.4";
$ftp_user_name = "username";
$ftp_user_pass = "password";
$port_number = 123

$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, $port_number);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
}
else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}
// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
```

The archive is a big file less that `2GB`.

But after some seconds I see `There was a problem`.

---

**Second try:**

```
$url = 'http://site.com/archive.tar';

file_put_contents("archive.tar", fopen($url, 'r'));
```

---

**Third try:**

```
$fh = fopen(basename($url), "wb");
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

---

**Fourth try:**

```
$fp = fopen (dirname(__FILE__) . '/archive.tar', 'w+');//This is the file where we save the    information
$ch = curl_init($url);//Here is the file we are downloading, replace spaces with %20
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 50);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp); // write curl response to file
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_exec($ch); // get curl response
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

---

**Fifth one:**

```
function download($file_source, $file_target) {
    $rh = fopen($file_source, 'rb');
    $wh = fopen($file_target, 'w+b');
    if (!$rh || !$wh) {
        return false;
    }

    while (!feof($rh)) {
        if (fwrite($wh, fread($rh, 4096)) === FALSE) {
            return false;
        }
        echo ' ';
        flush();
    }

    fclose($rh);
    fclose($wh);

    return true;
}


set_time_limit(0);

var_dump(download($url, 'archive.tar')); // Returns bool(false)
```

---

I should thank many guys in SO for using their code, but still no luck.

Comment: Have you checked your `php.ini` file to make sure you're file uploading is configured properly?

Comment: I'm living in a perfect configured `cpanel` shared hosting (that a lot of other normal scripts are running without any problem in it). What exactly should I check? I can `phpinfo()`.

Comment: Check out the recommendations in this article. Note - there are some `.htaccess` parameters that you may be able to change! https://drupal.org/node/97193

Answer (score 0):

Try [`ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);`](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.ftp-get.php#94218).

Comment: Thank you, but even this didn't help. It waited more to respond but no difference at the end.