# Download array of files on same server as PHP script

Tags: php

I have an array or over 1,000 files that I need to download to my local PC from my server.

I need to keep it to replicate the same file/folder structure for each file.

Here is an example list of files:

```
/lib/Zend/EventManager/Filter/FilterIterator.php
/lib/Zend/EventManager/config.php
/lib/Zend/Text/Figlet/themes.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Analytics/DataEntry.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Analytics/AccountQuery.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Calendar/files.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Query.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Gbase/Feed.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Photos.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Photos/AlbumFeed.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Media/Extension/press.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Media/file.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/RecurrenceException.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/Comments.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/Recurrence.php
/lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/Rating.php
```

To create the folders, navigate to them with FTP, and then download them would take me all day long!  How can I do this with PHP?

These files cannot be accessed in the browser with a URL so I have to use the file path.

---

**UPDATE**

Here is what I have tried so far using PHP ZipArchive...

**files.txt**
Test file to test a sample of the files I will need.  Final result will be over 1,000 files

```
lib/Zend/EventManager/Filter/FilterIterator.php
lib/Zend/EventManager/config.php
lib/Zend/Text/Figlet/themes.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Analytics/DataEntry.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Analytics/AccountQuery.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Calendar/files.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Query.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gbase/Feed.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Photos.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Photos/AlbumFeed.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Media/Extension/press.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Media/file.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/RecurrenceException.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/Comments.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/Recurrence.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Extension/Rating.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Books/VolumeQuery.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Books/VolumeFeed.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Exif/themes.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/MimeBodyString.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/HttpAdapterStreamingProxy.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets/Extension/test.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Spreadsheets/ListEntry.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/Query.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/GroupQuery.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/EmailListRecipientQuery.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/Error.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/OwnerFeed.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/alias.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/MemberQuery.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/EmailListQuery.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Gapps/NicknameFeed.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/Exif.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/App/LoggingHttpClientAdapterSocket.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/App/Extension.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/App/MediaEntry.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/App/FeedEntryParent.php
lib/Zend/Gdata/App/AuthException.php
```

**download.php**

```
$zip = new ZipArchive();
$filename = "./test112.zip";

if ($zip->open($filename, ZipArchive::CREATE)!==TRUE) {
    exit("cannot open <$filename>\n");
}else{
    echo 'zip good';
}
//$zip->addFromString("testfilephp.txt" . time(), "#1 This is a test string added as testfilephp.txt.\n");
//$zip->addFile("lib/Zend/files2.txt" ,"lib/Zend/EventManager/test.php" );

// list of files to download
$lines = file('files.txt');

// Loop through our array of files from the files.txt file
foreach ($lines as $line_num =>$file) {
    //echo "Line #<b>{$line_num}</b> : " . htmlspecialchars($file) . "<br />\n";

    // Add files to Zip file incliuding folder structure
    $zip->addFile($file,$file);

    echo $file;
}

// show number of files in new zip file and close zip archive
echo "numfiles: " . $zip->numFiles . "\n";
echo "status:" . $zip->status . "\n";
$zip->close();
```

**Result**

This creates my zip file however instead of adding all files, it only adds the last file in my files array to the zip archive!  In this example that is `lib/Zend/Gdata/App/AuthException.php`

Comment: Why don't you just zip the entire folder on the server, and download the archive? That's how "many files" are usually transferred, here on the internet...

Comment: @Siguza the whole server files would be multiple GB and thousands of files that I dont need.  I need just certain files from each folder.  Thats just not practical

Comment: Do you have SSH access to the server? Because it would be easier to make a simple script that find and gzip the files.

Comment: @this.lau_ I do have SSH access

Comment: So make an script that iterates array and include in the zip the file of each iteration. You can create zip files with php. David Wash can help you: http://davidwalsh.name/create-zip-php

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download files from ftp server in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7793170/download-files-from-ftp-server-in-php)

Comment: I made a PHP script to zip the files and added the code to my question above.  The issue is it is only adding the last file ion my array instead of all files in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have SSH access, you could simply run this on the server:

```
# Change '*.php' to whatever you want to retrieve:
find . -name '*.php' -print | zip archive.zip -@
```

Then you can get the file archive.zip via scp or ftp.

Comment: Is there a way to define the list of files and folder streucture of those files I need though?  I have a PHP array of about 1,000 files with there folder path and file name.

Comment: You can define the files you need using the '-name' parameter. If you need more than one criteria. You can use -o: `find . -name '*.php' -o -name '*.css'`. Or do you mean you already have the list of files? In which case you can skip the find command: `cat yourlist.txt | zip archive.zip -@`.

Comment: Yes I have a list of 1,000 files with file path and name for each file on a new line.  I will try your new answer, thank